How to run failed/flaky tests using gradle.test-retry
inside build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.gradle.test-retry' version '1.0.0'
}

test {
    retry {
        failOnPassedAfterRetry = true
        maxFailures = 3
        maxRetries = 2
    }
}


i configured above in build.gradle.
i am getting error retry is not configured.
here i am using java11, Gradle 7.1
Any other way to use this
i tried above code. and i am getting retry is not configured
Any suggestion where to modify

